# Jquery slideToggle close event triggered just after open

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a side menu like below:

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul class="sideMenu nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="dontHide">First menu</li>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="sideMenu nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="dontHide">test2</li>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="sideMenu nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="dontHide">test3</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

`nav` and `nav-sidebar` are `bootstrap` classes
here jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sideMenu').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).children(':not(.dontHide)').slideToggle();
        console.log("Clicked")
    });
})
```

As You can see it should toggle children

for starting hidden I use this css:

```
.nav-sidebar > li :not(.dontHide){
display:none;
}
```

Problem is with that the slide is triggered to close just after click which should open it.

Here Jsfiddle: [CLICK](http://jsfiddle.net/5SCuT/)

Comment: If you down vote this question pls tell why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the following rule, which is hiding the `a` element within the `li` element.

```
.nav-sidebar > li :not(.dontHide){
    display:none;
}
```

I think it should be - because the `dontHide` class is applied to the `li` element not to its descendants

```
.nav-sidebar > li:not(.dontHide){
    display:none;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XyA8j/)

Comment: Thx. So the problem was just about empty space between li and not.

Comment: @szpic but that changes the complete meaning of the rule

Answer (score 1):

try this below solution

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sideMenu').on('click', function (e) {
            if( $(this).children(':not(.dontHide)').is(":visible"))
            {
                            $(this).children(':not(.dontHide)').slideUp();

            }else{
                            $(this).children(':not(.dontHide)').slideDown();

            }
            console.log("Clicked")
        });
    })
```

**NOTE** in css follow  **Arun P Johny** Suggestion

see  **[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5SCuT/7/)**

Comment: Even in the fiddle we can see it's not working for first and second menu